# anonymous fields in type declaration?

Tags: go

I came across this type declaration:

```
type Handler func(*Conn)

type Server struct {
  Handshake func(*Config, *http.Request) error
  Handler
}
```

(this is a simplified version of https://github.com/golang/net/blob/38c17adf51120973d1735785a7c02f8ce8297c5e/websocket/server.go#L55-L66

The second field in the `Server` structure is anonymous. There is just type and no name.

Here is the grammar for type declarations (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations):

```
TypeDecl     = "type" ( TypeSpec | "(" { TypeSpec ";" } ")" ) .
TypeSpec     = identifier Type .
```

and it clearly requires an identifier name. But yet the section that I referenced that contains the grammar, also mentions anonymous fields.

I do not understand why this syntax is correct and how anonymous fields are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the part of the grammar that has to do with structures, not just types.  See: [Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and the use of `AnonymousField`.  Looking just at the production for `TypeSpec` is focusing attention on the wrong place.  Instead, look at `FieldDecl`; the grammar shows that we have two possibilities: named fields (`IdentifierList Type`), or anonymous fields (`AnonymousField`).

Anonymous fields are typically used for [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).  In your example, a `Server` will act like a `Handler` because it has embedded that field.